# how to update all rows with matching column in same table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i update all rows (a column in all rows) against a specific fk_ID in a table where the matching column also exist in the same table against different fk_ID.

For Example
I have a Table **A** it has column ID, Item, Status

| fk_ID | Item | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | AB | Y |
| 10 | AS | N |
| 11 | AX | N |
| 10 | AD | N |
| 11 | AB | N |
| 11 | AD | Y |

I want to change the status of all rows with fk_ID = 11 as it is against fk_ID = 10

I have tried following so far

```
update table b set b.status = b.status where b.fk_ID  = '11' Self JOIN ON b.fk_ID = 10;
```

Comment: What would be desired result?

Comment: Tha way is completely wrong. If you have 4 rows with FK 10 and 3 with FK 11, what is the logic you want apply?

Comment: @Littlefoot fk_ID = 11 status data should be updated as it is against Fk_ID = 10 for every Item e.g if item AB against fk_ID = 10 is Y the AB against fk_ID = 11 must be changed from N to Y

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update only the partial set of rows for `fk_id` of 10 where there is a matching `item` for a `fk_id` of 11 then you can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT item, status
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  fk_id = 11
) src
ON (dst.fk_id = 10 AND src.item = dst.item)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET status = src.status;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (fk_ID, Item, Status) AS
SELECT 10, 'AB', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'AS', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'AX', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'AD', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'AB', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'AD', 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

After the merge then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | FK_ID | ITEM | STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10 | AB | N |
> | 10 | AS | N |
> | 11 | AX | N |
> | 10 | AD | Y |
> | 11 | AB | N |
> | 11 | AD | Y |

---

If you want to change all the values (to remove the items that do not exist for then `fk_id` of 11 and then insert/update those that are new/modified) you need two statements:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE fk_id = 10
AND   item NOT IN (SELECT item FROM table_name WHERE fk_id = 11);

MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT item, status
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  fk_id = 11
) src
ON (dst.fk_id = 10 AND src.item = dst.item)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET status = src.status
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (fk_id, item, status) VALUES (10, src.item, src.status);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | FK_ID | ITEM | STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10 | AB | N |
> | 11 | AX | N |
> | 10 | AD | Y |
> | 11 | AB | N |
> | 11 | AD | Y |
> | 10 | AX | N |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9e5bb8102e4bcfba699bea3e43935ca6)*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the *primary key* of your table is `ITEM` and `FK_ID` and you want to *pass* the status from the `FK_ID` `10` to `11`.

This query gives you the overview of the *status*

```
select t11.*, t10.status s_t10
from table_name t11
join table_name t10 on t11.item = t10.item
and t11.fk_id = 11 and t10.fk_id = 10;

     FK_ID IT S S_T10
---------- -- - -
        11 AB N Y
        11 AD Y N
```

So you expect two rows to be updated.

You may use this join query as an *updateble join view* as follows

```
update (        
select t11.*, t10.status status_t10
from table_name t11
join table_name t10 on t11.item = t10.item
and t11.fk_id = 11 and t10.fk_id = 10)
set status = status_t10;
2 rows updated.
```

Result

```
select * from table_name

     FK_ID IT S
---------- -- -
        10 AB Y
        10 AS N
        11 AX N
        10 AD N
        11 AB Y  <<--- update
        11 AD N  <<--- update
```

Note that the above assumption about the `PK` must be valid (or at least a unique index must be defined, as otherwise Oracle fails with `ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`.

This is meaningfull, as if you have more rows with the *same `item`* in the `FK_ID = 10` - what should you use for the update??